# Find last n entries ordered by association

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

I have a table `Stories` and a table `Post`. Each `Story` contains multiple `Posts` (`Story.hasMany(models.Post);`, `Post.belongsTo(models.Story);`)

What I'm trying to achieve is to list the first 10 Stories ordered by `Posts.createdAt`. So it might be possible that the first entry is the oldest Story but with a very new Post.

What I'm trying right now is the following:

```
var options = {
    limit: 10,
    offset: 0,
    include: [{
        model: models.sequelize.model('Post'),
        attributes: ['id', 'createdAt'],
        required: true
    }],
    order: [
        [models.sequelize.model('Post'), 'createdAt', 'DESC'], 
        ['createdAt', 'DESC']
    ],
    attributes: ['id', 'title', 'createdAt']
};

Story.findAll(options)...
```

Which gives me this SQL query:

```
SELECT "Story".*, "Posts"."id" AS "Posts.id", "Posts"."createdAt" AS "Posts.createdAt" 
FROM (SELECT "Story"."id", "Story"."title", "Story"."createdAt" 
      FROM "Stories" AS "Story" 
      WHERE ( SELECT "StoryId" 
              FROM "Posts" AS "Post" 
              WHERE ("Post"."StoryId" = "Story"."id") LIMIT 1 ) IS NOT NULL 
      ORDER BY "Story"."createdAt" DESC LIMIT 10) AS "Story" 
  INNER JOIN "Posts" AS "Posts" ON "Story"."id" = "Posts"."StoryId" 
ORDER BY "Posts"."createdAt" DESC, "Story"."createdAt" DESC;
```

The problem here is that if the 11th entry has a very new post it is not displayed in the top 10 list.

How can I get a limited list of stories ordered by `Posts.createdAt`?

Answer (score 2):

Why are you using two nested subselects? That's ineffective, might produce expensive nested loops, and still does not return what you are looking for.

As a start, you can cross-join Stories and Posts, order by the creation timestamp from Posts. But this still might scan the entire table.

Have a look at this presentation:
http://www.slideshare.net/MarkusWinand/p2d2-pagination-done-the-postgresql-way
But I have no idea, how you can bring that into your model :-(

Comment: Thanks for the slideshare. I really like the idea of omitting the offset.